# Sails.js Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: reactjs, axios, sails.js

I'm creating a single page application using sails.js and reactjs and using JWT as authentication for protected requests. during the login process login request works as expected and able to login successfully. After that when I'm trying to request other requests with bearer token, browser shows following error message.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:1337/monitoringurl' from origin >'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field >authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight >response.

Below is my cors settings in sails config/security.js:

> cors: {
>      allRoutes: true,
>      allowOrigins: ["http://localhost:3000"],
>      allowCredentials: true,
>   }

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the answer for my own question. I had to change config/security.js as following:

> cors: {
>    allRoutes: true,
>    allowOrigins: ["http://localhost:3000"],
>    allowCredentials: true,
>    allowRequestHeaders: "content-type, authorization"
>   }

Comment: almost overlooked **allowRequestHeaders**, works like a charm!